# How to disable past time in TimePickerDilog kotlin

Tags: android, datetime, kotlin

I have use this dependncy **implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:4.2.3'** for timepickerdialog. **How to diasble past time but when select current date in a datepicker**, but when usr select future date so user can select any time. **I have done this code but I did n't understand how to apply check for time so user can't select past time when user select current date & user can select any time in  when user select future date**.

```
   val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        val tpd = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
            { view, hourOfDay, minute, second ->
                if (cal.getTimeInMillis() >= cal.getTimeInMillis()) {
                    //it's after current
                    val hour = hourOfDay % 12
                    binding.editChooseTime.setText(
                        java.lang.String.format(
                            "%02d:%02d %s", if (hour == 0) 12 else hour,
                            minute, if (hourOfDay < 12) "AM" else "PM"
                        )
                    )
                    getTime= hourOfDay.toString() +":"+minute+":"+second
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Invalid Time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            },
            cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
            cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
            true
        )
        tpd.setMinTime(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
            cal.get(Calendar.SECOND)) // MIN: hours, minute, secconds
        tpd.show(supportFragmentManager, "TimePickerDialog")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CalenderView in Kotlin, and then use its built-in function

```
addDecorator()
```

implement it like..(JAVA)

```
 binding.calendarView.addDecorator(new DayViewDecorator() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay day) {
            return day.isBefore(CalendarDay.today()); // Disable Days Before Today.
        }

        @Override
        public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {
            view.setDaysDisabled(true);
        }
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Please check above logic or tell me how to disable past time for today and user can select any time in  future in TimePickerDilog.

Comment: I used material Calender view like below.
            <com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/calendarView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:mcv_showOtherDates="all"
                app:mcv_selectionColor="#00F"
                />
and then i got its inbuild function. which I mentioned above.